# mySQL case when only returning 1 result

Tags: mysql, case-when

No idea why this is returning the first result only. The date is a Date format not datetime. I've only started using MySQL from using ORACLE and this is doing my head in.

```
SELECT *,

   CASE d_date

     WHEN max(d_date) THEN 'Today'

     WHEN date_add(max(d_date), interval -1 day) THEN 'Yesterday'

     ELSE 'other'

  END dateID

FROM mike.Tble
```

Comment: End, dateid ...missing a comma

Comment: Provide sample data, the result you are getting and the expected result.

Comment: Hi SoulRayder, there is no need for a comma since dateID is the alias to the case statement.

Comment: Hi Viki888, the table "Tble" has about 1k lines and the result is only returning the first time of "Tble".

Comment: I can understand your problem. To provide solution for your problem, you can provide sample data, resultset you are getting and your expected result.

Comment: Ok, I think I worked it out, max(d_date) only gives the first line of the max(value), in ORACLE it gives you a column populating everything with the max. I'll find a solution then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When aggregate function like MAX used it returns single record with max value. Thus my understandings need a sub query. I could not find how to optimize this query for a large record but I have following and lets optimize this for large records.

```
set @today = (SELECT max(d_date) FROM mike.Tble);
set @yesterday = (SELECT date_add(max(d_date), interval -1 day) FROM mike.Tble);

SELECT *, CASE d_date

     WHEN @today THEN 'Today'

     WHEN @yesterday THEN 'Yesterday'

     ELSE 'other'

  END AS dateID

FROM mike.Tble
```

Note: I edited query and its performance is better then last query

Comment: Hi Muhammed, THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH MATE! You are a legend!! I used a set and was not using it in the same way as the DEFINE. I REALLY APPRECIATE IT

Comment: my pleasure. :)